# Is there a GMLib installer for Delphi XE8?

Tags: delphi, gmlib, delphi-xe8

Is there a Delphi XE 8 installer yet?

I have tried to use the XE7 installer DPK package, but it doesn't appear to have the correct defines.

Comment: in some days. It is nearly ready

Comment: Excellent News!  Thanks for all you do on this!

Comment: Any update on a new version for XE8?  It's been a few months.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have had a personal problems (a traffic accident) and I've not been able to work in it. In few days I will return to my normal live. Sorry again